# Invoke OnClick when clicking, not when releasing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button that changes an image.
If I click on the button the image changes, but there is a white flash.
If I click the button but don't release the mouse, the image stays white (missing sprite).
How can I make the button run the attached image switching code instantaneously when clicked, not when released?

Example:

```
public void ChangeImage() {       
        image.sprite = img;
        //current = img;
        //current2 = img2;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("playerIndex", 1);
    }
```

I added this function to a button's OnClick() method in the editor.

Comment: Can you post some code examples of where this is happening?

Comment: @AaronJones example added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use EventTrigger component, attached to your button and set it with "pointerDown"